# Joomla long slow queries resulting in 503 Error

Tags: joomla3.0

Currently I have a Joomla 3.6.2 news website. Here we display news etc etc.

Now daily we upload tons or articles, we have a login system for paid subscribers.

The problem is that I have some "long slow queries' running which is eating up my resources.

I have 4 CPU cores 3.0 GHz and 7GB of RAM. Every few seconds the CPU and RAM kick up to a 100% and then drop slowly again. Which results in a 503 on the website.

As you can see this is quite annoying. Now my host told me that the following queries are causing this issue;

```
1. Executed 3h 55m 25s ago for 47.63166 sec on Database --> *********
Date: 2016-10-11 05:25:56 Query_time: 47.631660 Rows_examined: 179766: Rows_sent 10757 Lock_time: 0.000539
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.alias, a.introtext, a.fulltext, a.checked_out,
   a.checked_out_time, a.catid, a.created, a.created_by, a.created_by_alias,
   CASE WHEN a.modified = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
   THEN a.created ELSE a.modified END as modified, a.modified_by,
   uam.name as modified_by_name,
   CASE WHEN a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
   THEN a.created ELSE a.publish_up END as publish_up,
   a.publish_down, a.images, a.urls, a.attribs, a.metadata,
   a.metakey, a.metadesc, a.access, a.hits, a.xreference, a.featured,
   a.language, LENGTH(a.fulltext) AS readmore,
   CASE WHEN badcats.id is not null THEN 0 ELSE a.state END AS state,
   c.title AS category_title, c.path AS category_route,
   c.access AS category_access, c.alias AS category_alias,CASE WHEN a.created_by_alias > ' ' THEN a.created_by_alias ELSE ua.name END AS author,ua.email AS author_email,parent.title as parent_title, parent.id as parent_id, parent.path as parent_route, parent.alias as parent_alias,ROUND(v.rating_sum / v.rating_count, 0) AS rating, v.rating_count as rating_count,c.published, CASE WHEN badcats.id is null THEN c.published ELSE 0 END AS parents_published FROM sxm_content AS a LEFT JOIN sxm_categories AS c ON c.id = a.catid LEFT JOIN sxm_users AS ua ON ua.id = a.created_by LEFT JOIN sxm_users AS uam ON uam.id = a.modified_by LEFT JOIN sxm_categories as parent ON parent.id = c.parent_id LEFT JOIN sxm_content_rating AS v ON a.id = v.content_id LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT cat.id as id FROM sxm_categories AS cat JOIN sxm_categories AS parent ON cat.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt WHERE parent.extension = 'com_content' AND parent.published != 1 GROUP BY cat.id ) AS badcats ON badcats.id = c.id WHERE a.access IN (1,1,5) AND c.access IN (1,1,5) AND CASE WHEN badcats.id is null THEN a.state ELSE 0 END = 1 AND (a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2016-10-11 10:25:09') AND (a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_down >= '2016-10-11 10:25:09') ORDER BY c.lft, CASE WHEN a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN a.created ELSE a.publish_up END DESC , a.created;
```

I am quite new when it comes to these queries and correct me if I am wrong, I see that the query is trying to pull info from the articles table.

I am not sure why it would go through the whole table, I don't display all the articles on 1 page, nor do I have pagination where all articles from 1 category or more are being displayed.

This just happened out of the blue. I didn't make any changes to the website, no updating. Only thing I installed was a SSL Certificate.

I am also using CloudFlare as my CDN which takes quite a big load of the web-server. I don't use the Joomla cache but instead I use JOTCache simply because of the fact that I can exclude certain position on the website that I don't want cached.

We have around the 5k unique visitors per day.

Comment: It may be that you could do with an extra index on a column. If you are still seeking an answer to this, would you post an explain plan? I assume this is MySQL?